# Error while joining two tables in laravel controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Joining two tables showing error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name 'transaction_master ' "
```

But in my database `transaction_master` is exists.

The following query:

```
$trans_results= DB::table('report_master as rm')->join('transaction_master ', 'transaction_master.id','=','rm.id')->select('transaction_master.name as transactionID')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DB::table('report_master')
    ->join('transaction_master', 'report_master.id', '=', 'transaction_master.id')
    ->select('transaction_master.name as transactionID')
    ->get();
```

Read - [Laravel Query Builder **Joins**](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reverse the `transaction_master.id` and the `rm.id` in your join